# Split action bar not transparent

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface, android-widget

I've applied a custom theme to make my tabs and action bar transparent. But when I add the splitActionBarWhenNarrow attribute to the manifest the bottom action bar is no longer transparent. Does anyone know how to make the split action bar maintain the style I applied?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you styled both the regular action bar and the split action bar?  The two are actually styled separately.

Regular action bar is styled with `actionBarStyle` while split action bar is styled with `actionBarSplitStyle`.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a transparent color for `android:backgroundSplit` property will work.